# Jquery click function problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

New to jQuery I am trying to have an image that when I click on it I want to move up a certain amount of pixels then when another image is clicked go back down to the original state?

so far i  have tried this

```
$(".wrap").click(function(){
  $(this).css("margin-top", "-15px");
});
```

I just cant figure out how to make it move down to its original place
thanks

Comment: Make a fiddle of it, and share with us.

Comment: do you mean when you click again get original margin-top value?

Answer (score 0):

Place it in `document.ready` and use latest JQuery source file:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".wrap").on('click',function(){
  $(this).css("margin-top", "-15px");
  });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

```
$("img.wrap").click(function(){
    $("img.wrap").css("margin-top", "0px");
    $(this).css("margin-top", "-15px");
});
```

Comment: There is no difference between `$(".wrap")` and `$(this)` in this case.

Comment: It's different, `$(".wrap")` select all elements with class `wrap` and `$(this)` will target only clicked `.wrap` element

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap it in [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready)

And [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css) may not apply `margins` so use javascript `marginTop` like,

```
$(function(){
    $(".wrap").click(function(){
        this.style.marginTop='-15px';
    });
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/g47ZE/)

Answer (score 0):

For better look use [**Jquery animate**](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$( ".wrap" ).click(function() {
$(this).animate({
 top: "15px",
}, 500);
                              });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question. I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/chz9A/) to help you find a solution. Please have a look at the fiddle and the code snippet below. Appreciate your time.

```
$('.sample img').bind('click',function(){
    $('.sample img').removeAttr('style');
    $(this).css('top',-5);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this:

```
var mt = $('.wrap').css('margin-top');
$(".wrap").click(function(){
  if($(this).css('margin-top') == '-15px'){
   $(this).css('margin-top',mt);
  } else {
   $(this).css("margin-top", "-15px");
  }
});
```